# Tracing interrupts in Linux kernel

Tags: linux-kernel, interrupt, trace

What is the best way to trace interrupts all the way from ring3 to ring0?

For example, for the clock interrupt:
I want to see all the called functions starting from function in the interrupted user-mode process down to scheduler_tick().

I can do it manually by running gdb with QEMU, however it's quite cumbersome.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps *[ftrace](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/trace/ftrace.txt)* is what you want.

It allows you to keep track of the kernel function calls. You have to manually set all the functions that you want to trace. Then, the kernel will keep track of those function in a buffer that you can read later.